# notation question: What is $\nabla^{l}$ where $l\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, gradient-flows

Does  $\nabla^{l}$ where $l\in \mathbb{N}$ mean anything?

Could it mean dimension?

We do have $\nabla^{2}=\Delta$, but I've never seen $\nabla^{3}$ .

Found it in page 17

http://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.0926v2.pdf

thank you

Comment: In this case it appears to be a multilinear form consisting of the $l$-th derivatives, similar to $D^k f$ where $f:\mathbb R^n \to\mathbb R^m$. $D^k f [v_1, \ldots, v_k]$ is then defined by
$$D^k f [v_1, \ldots, v_k] = D(D^{k-1} f [v_2, \ldots, v_k])[v_1]$$
Where $Df[v] = v^T \nabla f$ for the usual gradient and a direction $v$.